# Spring filtered request

Tags: java, jquery, spring, filter, request

I'm looking for a way to make filtered requests through SpringBoot Applications. Through query strings I have to create methods that allow me to return a filtered data structure. For example
    GET /stats?field=Popo2011&filter={"Popo2011": {"$bt": [1000, 10000]}}
This is an example of a Get request with which I return only a part of the data structure.
I ask how we can implement such a method / request

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/stats", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public DataStructure getFilteredStats(@RequestParam(name="field) String field,
    @RequestParam(name="filter") String filter) {
    ...
```

You can then parse the filter String using a JSON library.